# How to speed up SpaCy for dependency parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am using spacy to specifically get all amod (adjective modifier) in many files (around 12 gigs of zipped files). I tried getting it to work on a folder of only 2.8 MB and it took 4 minutes to process it!

Here is my code till now:

```
with open("descriptions.txt", "w") as outf:
    canParse = False
    toParse = ""
    for file in getNextFile():
        # Open zip file and get text out of it
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as zf:
            with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(os.path.basename(file)[:-3]+"txt"), encoding="utf-8") as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    if line[0:35] == "*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG":
                        canParse = True
                    elif line[0:33] == "*** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG":
                        break
                    if canParse:
                        if line.find(".") != -1:
                            toParse += line[0:line.find(".")+1]

                            sents = nlp(toParse)
                            for token in sents:
                                if token.dep_ == "amod":
                                    outf.write(token.head.text + "," + token.text + "\n")

                            toParse = ""
                            toParse += line[line.find(".")+1:len(line)]
                        else:
                            toParse += line
```

Is there anyway to speed up spacy (or my python code in general) for this very specific use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your code a bit to use `nlp.pipe()`, which processes texts in batches and is much faster, and disable the components that you don't need (either with `nlp.pipe()` as below or when loading the model).

```py
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, disable=["tagger", "ner"]):
    # process, e.g.:
    print(doc)
```

See more details and examples: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#processing

You may also want to use multiprocessing with the `n_process` argument to `nlp.pipe()`.